# Folder/Directory Creation on Deployment Targets

Tags: c#, octopus-deploy

I am deploying a small script to the target PC using Octopus Deploy but the script is not generating a new folder on the target machine. Is there a problem in my code or is it a problem with the deployment setup?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class FolderCreation
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string _basePath = @"c:\OD_Test";
        try
        {
            string dateFolder = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string path = $"{_basePath}\\{dateFolder}";

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the community step for creating a folder?

Comment: What do you mean by community step?

Comment: This one... https://library.octopus.com/step-templates/7eaad6c2-fd5c-40a4-b880-350c983dc51d

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I was only supposed to add the information inside the Main method and not write out a class itself.

Comment: Good stuff. You can add your own answer to explain that, and then mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Octopus Deploy only allows script files to be accepted. I was NOT
supposed to create a class itself but only include the information 
inside the main method. Functions can be added by using OD's script
modules.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  there can be many possible issues in the code.
Ideally when you post, please post the details of the exception.

I suspect two things:
-  your parent directories are not present and that's why your create directory is failing.
- the code does not have permission to create directory in the existing path.

You can know this by the exception type which is get in the catch block.
Directory.CreateDirectory throws below exceptions in case it is not successful:

- **IOException** - The directory specified by path is a file.
- **UnauthorizedAccessException** - The caller does not have the required permission.
- **ArgumentException**  - path is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters. You can query for invalid characters by using the GetInvalidPathChars() method.  OR  path is prefixed with, or contains, only a colon character (:).
- **ArgumentNullException** - path is null.
- **PathTooLongException** - The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length.
- **DirectoryNotFoundException** - The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).
- **NotSupportedException** - path contains a colon character (:) that is not part of a drive label ("C:\").

*NOTE: Details of exceptions thrown by CreateDirectory is taken from [documentation at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2).*